# Describing a group of children - year or years, old or olds

Tags: grammaticality, singular-vs-plural, measure-expressions

Is this sentence correct if I describe a group of children?

> Children 6-7 years olds.

Answer (score 1):

You can say, "Children 6-7 years old", or "6-7-year-old children".

When used as a "normal" adjective, a number and unit are combined with a hyphen and the unit is given in the singular. "A 10-foot pole", "a 6-year-old child", "the 12-parsec Kessel run", etc.

When used as a predicate adjective, the number and unit are not hyphenated and the unit is given as a plural if the number is not 1. "She is 6 years old." "The house is one floor." Etc.

Comment: I might write "6-7" as "6-to-7" in this situation: _6-to-7-year old children_. If the age gap is only two years (as it is in this example), I might also employ "or", depending on the context: _6- or 7-year-old children_.

Comment: It is also idiomatic to speak of  a group of young children as *five to six year olds*. You might say for instance: *We want ten to twelve year olds in this group and thirteen to fifteen year olds in that one.*.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the context, if it's a group of children 5-7 years of age, the correct sentence would be

> 6-7 year olds

is used to describe multiple children

such as in a sentence:

> it's a group of 6-7 year olds

where as:

> 6-7 years old

is used to describe a child that is 6-7 years of age.

The children word is not really needed here in the sentence, it doesn't make very much sense.

unless in a context of for example:

> Only children 6-7 years old allowed.